# Is there a way to use a custom partitionby in spark df writer?

Tags: apache-spark, partition-by

I have a dataset with a milliseconds timestamp field, like `create_time` of `bigint` type. And I want to write them into different hdfs directories with a formatted partition suffix like `xxx/pt=20220101`, `xxx/pt=20220102` ... It looks like that `partitionBy` method of
`DataFrameWriter` works for this. But it cannot get a udf(format the bigint milliseconds into a YYYYMMDD date) as its input which is not presented in the schema of the child plan.
For example,

```scala
spark.sql("select df1.*,df2.* from df1 join df2 on df1.key1 = df2.key2")
    .write
    .option("header", value = true)
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .partitionBy("my_udf(df2.key2)")
    .csv("./test/data")
```

It failed to run because spark cannot get that expression's type from `df1.*` and `df2.*`.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: df.withColumn("name col to partition", your_udf func)
and then use partitionBy("name col to partition")

Comment: I don't want to write the partitionBy column into my hdfs files.

Comment: Spark partitionBy() is a function of pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter class which is used to partition based on one or multiple column values while writing DataFrame to Disk/File system.

When you write Spark DataFrame to disk by calling partitionBy(), PySpark splits the records based on the partition column and stores each partition data into a sub-directory.